# Terminar ciclo while

Tags: java

Hola estoy creando un ciclo while el cual debe terminar al presionar el valor -1
dejo código

```
while(lectura.hasNext()){
                  fin= lectura.nextInt();
                  posiciones.add(fin);
                 }
```

como puedo finalizar el ciclo al presionar la tecla -1, ademas el rango de valores de entrada debe estar entre 1-99

Comment: si fin es igual a -1, hace un break que rompa el ciclo

Comment: Como haces la comparacion? la haces con un if? porque intente y no me funciono

Comment: el rango de valores varía entre 1 a 99 como podrías poner un -1? o lo que quieres es que cualquier valor que esté fuera de ese rango termine con el ciclo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola espero que te sirva

```
while (lectura.hasNext()) {
    fin = lectura.nextInt();
    if (fin == -1) {
        break;
    }
    if (fin >= 1 && fin <= 99) {
        posiciones.add(fin);
    }
}
```